# Appending sub template to a specific div inside the current template : Backbone

Tags: jquery, backbone.js, underscore.js

I have a backbone view and a subview each with it's own template. I want to append subview, but in a specific div inside the current view.

These are my view and subview templates:

```
<script type="text/template" id="containerTmpl">
  <div id="container">
      <div id="inner-container">
      </div>  
  </div>
</script>

<script type="text/template" id="photoTmpl">
    <img src="<?- url ?>" alt="" />
</script>
```

What I want to do is when I append photoTmpl to containertmpl, I want to append it inside inner-container. Currently in backbone view when I say

```
this.$el.append(view.render().el);
```

It empties container div contents and replaces it with photoTmpl div.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Get the inner container from the element, and render the subview in it:

```
this.$('#inner-container').append(view.render().el);
```